How can I make mypy correctly use my type hinting files?
I am using a package that does not provide its own type hints so I have built some but cannot see how to get mypy to use them - anyone able to help?  Here's my system:

Windows
Using poetry
Created type hint files *.pyi for external package bob
If I use poetry env info to locate the site-packages directory and in there create a directory bob-stubs and copy my *.pyi type hints, then mypy is happy, but this is hacky of course!
If I create a typings\bob-stubs directory in my own package and copy the *.pyi files there, then mypy appears to try and type check the typing hints (!) and throws new errors!
If I move the type hint files elsewhere and try to set mypy_path in a mypy.ini file, I can see mypy read the mypy.ini file (using -vv) but it seems to ignore the hint files.

I've been going around in circles trying get this to work - anyone able to point me in the right directions?

Why is the bob-stubs version hacky? Stub files for many projects are installed as separate packages like this. The only thing hack is that you appear to be copying the files into site-packages by hand, rather than properly packaging them.

With "typings directory" approach you can just ask mypy to ignore_errors = true in "overrides" config section for that directory.

@chepner The general approach is not but I'm having to manually edit my virtualenv to add in stubs that I created.  There is currently no typing package for bob that I can install and have it place things in the correct place.

@STerliakov Do you mean ignore the errors when mypy tries to typecheck the typing stubs?

You can create such package and pip install it to avoid patching venv, you don't even need to publish it - local dependencies are a thing for most package managers. It's not that cumbersome - basically a pyproject.toml is all you need in simple cases.

And yes, I mean you can configure mypy to ignore all errors coming from a module - so it will use your stubs as a typing info source, but won't emit any errors there.

Since bob is an external package, perhaps it would be a service to the community if you did publish the stubs you've created?
